# Golang Pointer Reverse Linked List Confusion

Tags: pointers, go, linked-list

I'm new to Golang and am a bit confused as to how pointers work here and I'm using a reverse linked list question as an example.

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
  var prev *ListNode = nil
  for {
    if head == nil {
      break
    }
    temp := head
    head = head.Next
    temp.Next = prev
    prev = temp
  }
    return prev
}
```

In this case, `temp` and `head` is pointing to the same memory location. But if I were to put the line `temp.Next = prev` before `head = head.Next`, the `head.Next` will point to nil.

What is happening under the hood when we say `temp.Next = prev`. Are we saying that the structure `temp` is pointing at is now changed and thus if I were to put that line above `head = head.Next` then `head` is now pointing to this changed structure as well?

I thought in order to change the actual value of `head.Next`, we would have to dereference it?

I'm a little bit confused as to why this wouldn't work instead

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
  var prev *ListNode = nil
  for {
    if head == nil {
      break
    }
    temp := head   
    temp.Next = prev
    prev = temp
    head = head.Next <--- CHANGED ORDERING HERE
  }
    return prev
}
```

Comment: Unlike C, Go automatically dereferences pointers to structs. So that you can get to a struct member with `p.Next` if `p` is a pointer **or** if `p` is a struct variable.

Comment: I had no idea that was the case, I just never really questioned changing structs fields until now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work because you're invalidating `head` on the first iteration. Here's the flow:

```
temp := head   
// Since temp is a pointer, any modifications made to it will also
// impact head. So when you set temp.Next here, you're also setting
// head.Next. Since prev is always nil on the first iteration, you've
// set head.Next = nil.
temp.Next = prev
prev = temp
// This will set head to nil, always.
head = head.Next
```

In the correct version, updating `head = head.Next` before any writes happen to it means you've moved on to the next element already and so it is safe to overwrite the value.

Effectively what the second version does is snip off all elements of the list except the first one. If you didn't make a reference to the second element before calling this function, then they are now off in limbo and will get garbage-collected.

Updates based on comments:
When you do something like `temp := head`, you are saying "create a pointer called `temp` and point it to the same thing that `head` points to." If you then modify the thing that `temp` is pointing to (like for example, doing `temp.Next = prev`) you will also see the changes when reading the data that `head` points to since it is still pointing at the same place.

When you then do `head = head.Next` you are saying "update `head` to point to wherever `head.Next` is pointing." This updates `head` itself instead of the data that it is pointing to, so you won't see any changes related to `temp`.

Here is a good resource to learn more about pointers: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/26/understand-go-pointers-in-less-than-800-words-or-your-money-back

Comment: When I set `head = head.Next` it should also set `temp` to be equal to `head.Next` right? But why is it that when I set `temp.prev = prev` afterwards it no longer affects head?

Comment: is it because `head = head.Next` assigns it to another pointer rather then altering it? So `head` and `temp` are no longer related?

Comment: I added some details about how pointers work, let me know if that helps at all. But to the second comment, yes, setting `head = head.Next` makes `head` point to different data than `temp`, so modifying the two are now independent.